# SQLAlchemy insert or update example

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In Python, using SQLAlchemy, I want to insert or update a row.  I tried this:

```
existing = db.session.query(Toner)
for row in data:
    new = Toner(row[0], row[1], row[2])
```

It does not work.  How do I INSERT or UPDATE `new` into `Toner` table?  I suspect it's done with merge, but I cannot understand how to do that.

Comment: There is no insert-or-update in (standard) SQL.  You will have to fetch and update existing objects manually, then insert those that do not exist yet.  Alternatively you will have to sidestep the ORM and issue your backend-dependent SQL manually.

Comment: @Ferdinand Beyer Wouldn't session.merge() (http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/session.html#merging) work in my case?

Comment: `session.merge()` does something completely different: It adds an object to the session that originates from another session.  For instance, if there's an object with ID 42, `session.merge()` will fetch a row for ID 42 from the database, and return a new object that represents the same database row.  This has nothing to do with `INSERT` or `UPDATE`.

Comment: your example code is confusing: it shows that your retrieve `Toner` objects from the database, which means they already exist; then you try create `Toner` objects again with same fields. Please expand your example to a more realistic one.

Comment: Could you change the accepted answer since it has only downvotes and your comment on it shows that it didn't help you?

Comment: INSERT or UPDATE can be done, but an efficient implementation depends on the underlying SQLAlchemy database. It is different for MySQL and PostgreSQL.

Comment: This question doesn't make a lot of sense, becuase you have not explained what `Toner` is, how it is created or where it comes from. I am unable to reproduce your question.

Answer (score 158):

assuming certain column names...

**INSERT one**

```
newToner = Toner(toner_id = 1,
                    toner_color = 'blue',
                    toner_hex = '#0F85FF')

dbsession.add(newToner)   
dbsession.commit()
```

**INSERT multiple**

```
newToner1 = Toner(toner_id = 1,
                    toner_color = 'blue',
                    toner_hex = '#0F85FF')

newToner2 = Toner(toner_id = 2,
                    toner_color = 'red',
                    toner_hex = '#F01731')

dbsession.add_all([newToner1, newToner2])   
dbsession.commit()
```

**UPDATE**

```
q = dbsession.query(Toner)
q = q.filter(Toner.toner_id==1)
record = q.one()
record.toner_color = 'Azure Radiance'

dbsession.commit()
```

**or using a fancy one-liner using [MERGE](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.merge)**

```
record = dbsession.merge(Toner( **kwargs))
```

Comment: where does the `dbsession` come from ? O.o is it from `create_engine()` ?

Comment: So in case anyone's wondering where does the `dbsession` come from, it's probably from `Session()` or if you have Session factory with pre-config something like `MySession = sessionmaker(create_engine(...))` then `MySession()` to create this `dbsession`

Comment: update code will get: sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: No transaction is begun.

Comment: Does `merge` accept a list of objects or mappings?

Comment: About dbsession it's come from this import:     
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session as dbsession

Comment: record = dbsession.merge(Toner( **kwargs))
dbsession.commit()

Answer (score 16):

I try lots of ways and finally try this:

```
def db_persist(func):
    def persist(*args, **kwargs):
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        try:
            session.commit()
            logger.info("success calling db func: " + func.__name__)
            return True
        except SQLAlchemyError as e:
            logger.error(e.args)
            session.rollback()
            return False
        finally:
            session.close()

    return persist
```

and :

```
@db_persist
def insert_or_update(table_object):
    return session.merge(table_object)
```

Answer (score 13):

### INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ..

the sql:

```
INSERT INTO the_table (id, col1) VALUES (%s, %s) 
   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col1 = %s
```

in py code:
// test with sqlalchemy 1.4.x, use mysql

```py
def test_insert_or_update():
    insert_stmt = insert(the_table).values(
        id = 'xxx',
        col1 = 'insert value',
    )
    on_duplicate_key_stmt = insert_stmt.on_duplicate_key_update(
        # col1 = insert_stmt.inserted.data,
        col1 = 'update value',
        col2 = 'mark'
    )
    print(on_duplicate_key_stmt)
    session.execute(on_duplicate_key_stmt)
    session.commit()
```

NOTE: different sql dialect may have different sql statement   (sqlalchemy will handle that):

- mysql: INSERT ... ON DUPLICAT
- sqlite: INSERT ... ON CONFLICT
- postgres9.4 or greenplum6: not support

Answer (score 0):

There is no builtin function to do insert or update. However, you could query if a record exists first. Then you add it or update it:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
  
engine = create_engine(
    "sqlite:///foo.db"
)

Base = declarative_base()


class Toner(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'toner'
    toner_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    toner_color = Column(String(255))
    toner_hex = Column(String(255))

Base.metadata.tables['toner'].create(engine)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

newToner = Toner(toner_id = 1,
                 toner_color = 'blue',
                 toner_hex = '#0F85FF')

qry_object = session.query(Toner).where(Toner.toner_id == newToner.toner_id)

if qry_object.first() is None:
    session.add(newToner)
else:
    qry_object.update(newToner)
session.commit()
```

and you can check the result with

```
res = session.query(Toner).all()
for r in res:
    print({
        'toner_id': r.toner_id,
        'toner_color': r.toner_color,
        'toner_hex': r.toner_hex
    })
```

Comment: The update() method requires an iterable, else the line `qry_object.update(newToner)` will give an error